# TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-service

I am using AngularJs and Protractor for testing api data and trying getting response from the server using restapi and then display that data on console.
 
Bellow is my Code. 
  
My Service File:

```
module.exports = {getResponse : function ($http){

    $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data)
          var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log(jsonData);
          // this callback will be called asynchronously    
          // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
    }   

};
```

Testcase File :

```
 var helper = require('./helper');
 describe('A test suite', function() {  

   it('does something to myService', function() {
        var result = helper.getResponse();  
        console.log(result);    
   }); 
  });
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `$http` in your service delcaration?

```
angular.module('app').service('YourService', ['$http', function($http) {

// your code

}]);
```

Comment: No. I haven't include it in service declaration. Above displayed code are not a part of code, they are complete files. If you find that something is missing in these files. please rectify them. May be I am not right. You can provide your code too.